# Java: Creating a NEW Map with the information of another Map instead of creating a reference

Tags: java, dictionary, reference, hashmap

I couldn't find an exact answer to this problem so I'm just going to ask myself.

I have a `Map<Integer, State> states;` with information about a specific day. Each day the information of that day is saved in a `Map<Integer, DayLog> dayLog;` where the DayLog contains the saved `Map<Integer, State> states;`.

The problem is, when I change the realtime `states`, all saved `states` in the `dayLog` changes too, due to a created reference, and not newly created information.

How do I save the information in a new Map instead of just creating a reference?

Hope this is understandable.
Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Please show the relevant pieces of code instead of describing them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do a deep copy when you create your DayLog:

```
/**
 * Create a new DayLog object with the current set of states. 
 * This constructor will make a deep copy of the states so they cannot be
 * changed later outside of this log.
 * @param currentStates the states as they exist right now
 */
public DayLog(Map<Integer, State> currentStates) {
    this.states = new HashMap<>();
    for(Integer key : currentStates.keySet()) {
        State state = currentStates.get(key);
        State newState = new State(state); // assuming copy constructor
        this.states.put(key, newState);
    }
}
```

There might be multiple ways to accomplish this (clone, having a `state.archive()` method, or something) but this will be the basic methodology - create a map of the states as they exist right now and leave no refernces to the live data.

Alternatively, use a database - it's really good at, you know, storing data.

Comment: You might be able to be even more succinct with lambdas.

Comment: Probably. Haven't done Java professionally since before lambdas were a big thing. But if someone knows how to do them, they'll look at what this does and go "oh yeah, copy constructor, that's what I need!" and put it into whatever solution they use.

Comment: @duffymo I could also do better by not hiding `this.states` - it just leads to bugs doing it the way I did it there.

Comment: Agreed.  Your solution is not wrong.  Just pointing it out for interest sake, that's all

Comment: Fine answer. Quick improvement possible : iterating with `entrySet()` rather than `keySet()`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Can you tell me more about an alternative instead of creating a new state that needs to deep copy every variable of the old state? The problem is that the class State contains many variables and methods and even underclasses like Goal and Aggregation.

Comment: @Moorky You have to separate the data somewhere. The live data cannot be mixed with the old data. If you don't do a deep copy, then you have to clear your live data (as davidxxx's answer states) - but that also means you have to reconstruct your data if future states depend on past states. If you have to make a new object anyway, personally I'd lean on the side of making a snapshot. But really, you shouldn't be solving this problem at all: you should be using a database. It's really good at this.

Comment: @corsiKa I've never used a database before. But I'll look into it now.

Comment: @corsiKa I've just created a copy constructer for each class because this is the fastest way from my point right now. I'd have used a database or similar stuff, but I need to finish this program very soon. Your code worked perfectly fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> How do I save the information in a new Map instead of just creating a
>   reference?

You can create the `HashMap` with the constructor that takes as parameter a `Map` :

```
public HashMap(Map<? extends K, ? extends V> m)
```

From the Javadoc :

> Constructs a new HashMap with the same mappings as the specified Map.

It will put all elements in the new `HashMap`.

Then clear the initial `Map` : `map.clear()`.

Then as you add element in the initial Map, it will not have side effect on the just created `Map`.

Comment: This won't solve the problem though. `State s = new State(5); Map<Integer,State> map = new HashMap<>(); map.put(1,s); Map<Integer,State> newMap = new HashMap(map); s.setState(6); System.out.println(newMap.get(1).getState()); // prints 6, not 5`

Comment: If you clear the initial map after instantiation, it will.

Comment: Wait, what? No, it won't. The problem is that outside of the map someone is mutating the values. You have to break the new map's access to those values if you want to stop them from mutating them! Show me a MCVE that illustrates your point.

Comment: You make the supposition that the defensive copy is required by the op. In the actual context, nothing demands it. Doing a deep copy is actually not a requirement.

Comment: It does demand it though - clearing the map means losing access to all those state objects. You COULD, if you wanted, leave the old objects in the day log and use brand new objects in the live version, but really, why would you want to build them from scratch?

Comment: Here's an MCVE showing why clearing the map doesn't really do much - anything could have access to that State object outside of that map. http://ideone.com/WQn0Tf

Comment: your MCVE is Ok. It illustrates side effect when a defensive copy is not used. I agree with it. I say simply that without knowing where and how the objects are created, I cannot swear that the defensive copy is or is  not required. Referencing this point is valuable but explaining that it is the actual problem of the op is inaccurate.

Comment: Yeah this works in way, but not for my program unfortunately. I can't just clear the information in the inital map, as I still need it.